# MSBuild Error: refCount should not be less than 1?

Tags: .net, msbuild

Does anyone know what causes this error? I'm having trouble finding any information on it.

Comment: That's possible. It's coming out of a home-grown build / deployment system.

Comment: Try searching your code base for `refCount should not be`

Comment: It is the kind of diagnostic you'd get out of COM code, IUnknown::Release() is called on an object whose reference count says it should already have been destroyed.  Not good.  Finding it is up to you.