# MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: refCount should not be less than 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Does anyone know what this means? I am getting this error in my CI build (CruiseControl.Net + NAnt + MSBuild), locally this project compiles just fine...

```
My.Web.csproj: Error MSB4014: The build was aborted because of an internal failure.
Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: refCount should not be less than 1.
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInternalError(String message, Exception innerException, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Collections.CopyOnWriteDictionary\`2.CopyOnWriteBackingDictionary\`2.get_HasNoClones()
   at Microsoft.Build.Collections.CopyOnWriteDictionary\`2.set_Item(K key, V value)
   at Microsoft.Build.Collections.CopyOnWriteDictionary`2.System.Collections.IDictionary.set_Item(Object key, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.BuildItem..ctor(String itemName, ITaskItem taskItem)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.GatherTaskItemOutputs(Lookup lookup, TaskOutput taskOutputSpecification, String itemName, String propertyName, Object outputs)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.GatherGeneratedTaskOutputs(Lookup lookup, TaskOutput taskOutputSpecification, String taskParameterName, String itemName, String propertyName, ITask task)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.GatherTaskOutputs(TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, ItemBucket bucket)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteBucket(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, Int32 bucketNumber, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteTask(TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Lookup lookup)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskExecutionState.TaskEngineExecuteTask(TaskEngine taskEngine, TaskExecutionMode howTaskShouldBeExecuted, Lookup lookup)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskExecutionState.ExecuteTask()
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskExecutionModule.ExecuteTask(TaskExecutionState taskState)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetExecutionWrapper.SubmitNonIntrinsicTask(XmlElement taskNode, ITaskHost hostObject, ProjectBuildState buildContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetExecutionWrapper.ExecuteCurrentTask(ProjectBuildState buildContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetExecutionWrapper.ContinueRunningTasks(ProjectBuildState buildContext, TaskExecutionContext taskExecutionContext, Boolean startingFirstTask)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TargetExecutionWrapper.ContinueBuild(ProjectBuildState buildContext, TaskExecutionContext taskExecutionContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project.ExecuteNextActionForProjectContext(ProjectBuildState buildContext, Boolean initialCall)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project.CalculateNextActionForProjectContext(ProjectBuildState buildContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project.ContinueBuild(ProjectBuildState buildContext, TaskExecutionContext taskExecutionContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Project.BuildInternal(BuildRequest buildRequest)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.BuildProjectInternalInitial(BuildRequest buildRequest, Project project)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.BuildProjectInternal(BuildRequest buildRequest, ProjectBuildState buildContext, TaskExecutionContext taskExecutionContext, Boolean initialCall)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.EngineBuildLoop(BuildRequest terminatingBuildRequest)
   at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine.PostProjectEvaluationRequests(Project project, String[] projectFiles, String[][] targetNames, BuildPropertyGroup[] globalPropertiesPerProject, IDictionary[] targetOutputsPerProject, BuildSettings buildFlags, String[] toolVersions)

Unexpected error while compiling project 'My.Web'

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: refCount should not be less than 1.
```

Comment: Not any accepted answer here, but maybe the comments could point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418476/msbuild-error-refcount-should-not-be-less-than-1

Comment: Nope. I've seen this thread before I asked my question...

Comment: Post this to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: When you mean locally, are you running ccservice locally, running nant on the command line, or just building in Visual Studio?  Showing us the ccservice and nant script may help.  If it doesn't, then maybe attaching a sample project that can reproduce the problem is required.  For example, check to make sure the .net framework version you set in your nant script matches the version of the msbuild project.

Comment: Locally -- building in Visual Studio on dev workstation.

Comment: These are relevand targets from the .build file: <target name="clean"> <exec program="${msbuild.exe}" commandline="/nologo /verbosity:minimal /clp:PerformanceSummary /t:Clean" workingdir="${workingDirectory}" failonerror="true" /> </target> <target name="build"> <solution configuration="${buildConfig}" solutionfile="MySolution.sln" /> </target>

Comment: It does not allow me to post complete ccnet.congif file -- too big. This is how msbuild variable is defined in it: 
  <cb:define msbuild.exe="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" />

Comment: And I am not setting framework version in my .build file

Comment: Found the solution: instead of using <solution> in the build target I called msbuild directly with <exec>. Everything works now.

Comment: @Andrei, it would be better if you wrap this into an answer and accept it so that others know what has helped without scrolling through the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: instead of using `<solution>` in the build target I called msbuild directly with `<exec>`. Everything works now.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but I've read this solution 100 times now. Are you saying you were using solution and changed it to exec to call msbuild? Or you had exec calling msbuild and changed it to solution? I am having this problem now and don't know what to do.

Comment: I was using <solution>, then changed to <exec> to call msbuild.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem in a similar environment.  In my case, the project had a COM reference to the Active DS Type Library, which wasn't installed on the build server.

To fix the problem, I dropped the COM reference and added a reference to an interop assembly, which was then deployed to the build server.

Answer (score -1):

My problem it's similar with you, I'm have to eliminate two projects that relationship with my solution in mobil enviroment, that cause the conflict with the others projects in my solution.
My other projects are desktop, mvc, webapi enviroment.

I have to create a new solution for my others mobil projects